# Creating Links From A Homepage Using REACT and MUI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, create-react-app

I am trying to create a shopping cart app using react, I want a homepage with links to a checkout page, an address form, a payment form, and a review page. I have code for all of those pages, but when I run the react app it won't display the home page. I suspect that when I try to implement my code there is not a default homepage. Any ideas on how to fix this?

```js
import "./styles.css";
import { ProductDescription } from "./ProductDescription";
import { Box, Grid, Typography } from "@mui/material";
import { products } from "./products";
import { useState } from "react";
import MenuIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Menu";
import ExpandMoreOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/ExpandMoreOutlined";
import ShoppingCartIcon from "@mui/icons-material/ShoppingCart";
import { DenseAppBar } from "./DenseAppBar";
import { StandardImageList } from "./ImageList";
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Home = () => {
  return <p> Home Page</p>;
};
const Checkout = () => {
  return <p>Checkout Page </p>;
};
const PaymentForm = () => {
  return <p>Payment Form </p>;
};
const Review = () => {
  return <p>Review Page </p>;
};
const AddressForm = () => {
  return <p>Address Form </p>;
};

export default function App() {
  const [ordertotal, setordertotal] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Grid>
        <DenseAppBar />
      </Grid>
      <h1>Products</h1>
      <Typography>Your order total is {ordertotal}</Typography>
      <Typography>Your order tax is {ordertotal * 0.08}</Typography>
      <Grid item xs={1}>
        <MenuIcon />
      </Grid>

      <Grid container justifyContent="center">
        {products.map((p, i) => (
          <Grid item xs={2} key={i}>
            <ProductDescription
              {...p}
              ordertotal={ordertotal}
              setordertotal={setordertotal}
            />
          </Grid>
        ))}
      </Grid>
      {/*     
      <Grid>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <nav>
            <Link to="./Checkout">Checkout | </Link>
            <Link to="./PaymentForm">Payment Form | </Link>
            <Link to="./AddressForm">Address Form| </Link>
            <Link to="./Review">Review</Link>
          </nav>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/App.js" exact>
            {App}
            </Route>
            <Route path="./Checkout" component={Checkout}></Route>
            <Route path="./PaymentForm">{PaymentForm}</Route>
            <Route path="./AddressForm">{AddressForm}</Route>
            <Route path="./Review">{Review}</Route>
            </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </Grid> */}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Some code is commented out so I could get back to the original page I had created to try and solve the issue myself.

I expected a homepage with headers that when clicked would link to each respective page (the two forms, checkout, and review page).

Comment: You are declaring your router in a complex way that mess with the App rendering. If you follow the react router tutorial you should solve your problem https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/tutorial